# Send ArrayList inside ArrayList

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist

I have an ArrayList (A) that contains another 2 ArrayLists(B) , I am getting A's data from a json file, in the first activity I can see that A and B both are not empty, but when I pass A to another Activity or a fragment, A stays full but B becomes empty, All the objects used implements `Parcelable`, this is a snippet of the code used to send and retrieve the data :

```
           Intent myIntent = new Intent(LauncherActivity.this, AcceuilActivity.class);
                    myIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("listeOffres",projectsList);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                    finish();
```

and this is how I retrieve A that contains B                 `offresList=getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("listeOffres");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `Parceble` model file. Let's take an example of User here and check below code. Also, check the argument used to passing ArrayList in intent. If this may not help you then please provide more details.

```
protected User(Parcel in) {
    name = in.readString();
    ....
    gender = in.readString();
}


@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeString(name);
    ....
    parcel.writeString(gender);
}
```

Comment: You are right the generated Parcel doesn't implment how to read neither write the Lists, that's something  we should write on our own, this is my first time using it, so I didn't think that it will leave out the lists

Comment: If this answer is helpful for you then you can upvote the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it like this:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(LauncherActivity.this, AcceuilActivity.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("listeOffres",projectsList);
                startActivity(myIntent);
                finish();
```

and this for how to retrive data

```
 offresList = (ArrayList<ModelClass>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("listeOffres");
```

then implements Serializable  Like:

```
class ModelClass implements Serializable
{}
```